# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, rake

I have a local project, with rails and postgres. I threw it up on my AWS Amazon Linux AMI. I have run test projects with rails and postgres on the server. However when I uploaded my local project, and try to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation schema_migrations
```

I saw some similar issues, but none of them help. I do have the proper role setup and connected.

Comment: Have you created a role for postgresql?

Comment: I do have the role, funny thing is it worked for the create command. Triple checked the info.

Comment: Also, to verify, db:create works fine. but migrate does not.

Comment: Maybe try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE schema_migrations TO <your_role>;`

Comment: Do you have postgreSQL installed on the same EC2 box as your app? or are you using RDS or some other database system? Is this for a production app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're running `rake db:migrate` with `RAILS_ENV` as production or development.  Whichever it is (development by default), in your config/database.yml it will say the user, password, and database it is running on.  That user must have `ALL` privileges on the `public.schema_migrations` table.  If it does, and it's still not working, make sure that user has ALL privileges on the `public` schema.

Read more about manipulating postgres database privileges [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html).  Postgres has excellent documentation.

One more thing: if you're creating this database locally, and trying to create the initial database instead of actually running a migration, use rake `db:schema:load` instead of rake `db:migrate`. **Never** run this on production, as it will delete your data!